# Magento logs print array contents

Tags: arrays, magento, logging

Mage::log works fine for me, **except** when it comes to printing array info.

For example, if I have an array $result, and do this:

Mage::log('[CartController: getDeliverLeadTime(country): ' . $result . ')');

In my system.log file I just get:
[CartController: getDeliverLeadTime~(country): **Array**)

***I want it to print the actual structure and contents of the array, as a normal print_r would do.***

If I do a var_dump of the array I get nothing, i.e. [CartController: getDeliverLeadTime~(country): ).

If I do a print_r I get:
[CartController: getDeliverLeadTime~(country): 1)

This is a blocker for me as I can't debug what I need to - if anyone could shed any light on how to get Magento to actually print the contents of arrays in the logs, would be much appreciated.

I read on alanstorm.com that its meant to be happen by default, but its not for me.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to return [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) as a string, so `print_r($result, true)` should do the trick.

Comment: Max thanks a million for that! Works perfectly, that is a big relief. I can mark the question as answered in 7 minutes, will do so then. Thanks again, Paul.

Comment: @pokero don't forget to vote up and accept the answer if it helped you out

Comment: Nice to have print_r log stuff to your custom Magento log file.

Comment: huh. should be straightforward, but this messed me up a lot. easy fix.

Answer (score 2):

**Try it**

```
$array = array('ID' => 1, 'NAME' => 'Amaresh', 'EMAIL' => 'example@gmail.com');

Mage::log($array);
```

**Output**

```
2015-09-18T06:44:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [NAME] => Amaresh
    [EMAIL] => example@gmail.com
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on code below code,

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
Mage::log("Query product: ".print_r($collection->getData(), true),null,'test.log');
```

check file `test.log` in `var/log` folder.